# Issues of gazebo 2.0 used with ros-hydro

Tags: ros, gazebo-2

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I have just upgraded to gazebo 2.0, I use ros-hydro and ubuntu 12.04 32bit. It seems that the new gazebo is not compatible with ros, as when I start the gazebo with ros: roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch, I get the following error messages:

Error [Plugin.hh:141] Failed to load plugin /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so: libgazebo_common.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Error [Plugin.hh:141] Failed to load plugin /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libgazebo_ros_api_plugin.so: libgazebo_common.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Then there is no service provided by gazebo to spawn model using urdf, which is waited by the ros-gazebo interface programm spawn_model. Someone else also encounters the same problem: http://answers.ros.org/question/88826/plorblem-in-loading-gazebo-in-ros/

Thanks for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4635/issues-of-gazebo-2.0-used-with-ros-hydro/) by [mikegao88](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/439/mikegao88/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-10-09**:
Seems to me like it is exactly the same problem described in the answer 88826 as you well pointed out. Let's follow things in that answer and close this one.

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-10-09**:
Let me ask you another question: how did you install gazebo and ros-hydro-gazebo-pkgs? From debs? From source? Thanks.

**Comment by [mikegao88](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/439/mikegao88/) on 2013-10-10**:
Thanks for your reply! That question(88826) has been unfortunately closed by the manager of the ros forum, probably as it is a gazebo topic. I install both gazebo and ros-hydro-gazebo-pkgs from debs.

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-10-10**:
Ouch you are right, much a better place this. It's weird that you could install gazebo-2.0.0 and ros-hydro-gazebo-pkgs at the same time since gazebo-2.0.0 conflicts with < 2.3.3 version of these packages. 2.3.3 new versions should be available very soon and probably will solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The [integration document about Gazebo/ROS](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Install/Gazebo_and_ROS) should help to solve all problems related to the gazebo 2.0 (gazebo_current) release and the integration with ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikegao88](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/439/mikegao88/) on 2013-10-22**:
Thanks for your reply!

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-10-29**:
Could we mark this answer as solved, clicking that check button? That way I don't see it as "unanswered" any more. Thanks.